# aws cdk eks-blueprint fails with error Invalid type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-cdk, nginx-ingress

I am trying to use the nginx ingress controller addon in eks blueprint of aws cdk. The documentation is at https://aws-quickstart.github.io/cdk-eks-blueprints/addons/nginx/. However execution fails and print an error message:

```
Deployment failed: Error: Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named eks-blueprint failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: b"Error: UPGRADE FAILED: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):\nnginx-ingress:\n- controller.service.httpPort.enable: Invalid type. Expected: boolean, given: string\n- controller.service.httpsPort.targetPort: Invalid type. Expected: integer, given: string\n\n"
```

Code Snippet of my code:

```
 const addOns: Array<blueprints.ClusterAddOn> = [
      new blueprints.addons.ArgoCDAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.CalicoOperatorAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.MetricsServerAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.ClusterAutoScalerAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.AwsLoadBalancerControllerAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.VpcCniAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.CoreDnsAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.KubeProxyAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.EbsCsiDriverAddOn(),
      new blueprints.addons.ExternalDnsAddOn({hostedZoneResources: [GlobalResources.HostedZone]}) ,
      
  ];

  const stack = blueprints.EksBlueprint.builder()
      .account(props?.env?.account)      .region(props?.env?.region)
      .addOns(...addOns)
      .resourceProvider(GlobalResources.HostedZone ,new blueprints.LookupHostedZoneProvider(props?.dnsDomainName))
      .resourceProvider(GlobalResources.Certificate, new CreateCertificateProvider('wildcard-certificate', `*.${props?.dnsDomainName}`, GlobalResources.HostedZone))
      .addOns(new blueprints.addons.NginxAddOn({
        certificateResourceName: GlobalResources.Certificate,
        externalDnsHostname: props?.dnsDomainName!
    }))
      .useDefaultSecretEncryption(false)
      .clusterProvider(new blueprints.MngClusterProvider({
        version: KubernetesVersion.V1_24,
        desiredSize: 1,
        maxSize: 3,
        instanceTypes: [new InstanceType('t3.medium')],
        amiType: NodegroupAmiType.AL2_X86_64,
        nodeGroupCapacityType: CapacityType.SPOT,
      }))
      .build(scope, 'eks-blueprint');
  }
```

I expect cdk to pass valid inputs to the helm chart. If remove the line
`certificateResourceName: GlobalResources.Certificate,`
the deployment is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now tracked in https://github.com/aws-quickstart/cdk-eks-blueprints/issues/672#issuecomment-1536376394.
It will be fixed shortly.